# Scaling SVG Strokes

Tags: svg

I have imported a SVG File. I have generated a 3D object out of it and printed it on a 3D printer. But the Lines are too small (see gray area in the provided image). I have a lot of these line and I'm looking for a simple method to scale them (make them thicker). Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If they were a single stroke there are a few methods to adjust thickness in Blender, since they already have a double stroke it is probably less work to adjust them in whatever application you designed them with

Comment: is there maybe a way to convert them to a single stroke? I created this in Incscape (via pathtracing) but I found no solution there either

Comment: Inkscape now has a line drawing trace method